# K-means clustering of Laplacian matrix eigenvectors or finding which eigenvector has maximum value

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, laplacian, graph-laplacian, cut-space

I've read this [article](http://people.csail.mit.edu/dsontag/courses/ml14/notes/Luxburg07_tutorial_spectral_clustering.pdf). In this article. it's explained that $k$-eigenvectors of a Laplacian matrix are an approximation of RatioCut for $k$ clusters. To prove this, a matrix named $H$ is defined as follow:
\begin{equation}
h_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{|A_j|} & \text{if $v_i\in A_j$} \\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

It's shown that the $k$ eigenvectors associated with $k$ lowest eigenvalues ($U$) are the approximation of the matrix $H$. To find the $k$ clusters on graphs, it's said that we can consider every row of $U$ as a point in the space and apply the $k$-means on them. My question is that matrix $H$ is so specific. Every row of it has only one non-zero value and all the others are zeros. To approximate the clusters, why don't we find the index of the maximum value in every row of $U$ and select that index as the cluster number for that node?